# Prevent SQL injection in oracle

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, ado.net

firstly i tried using following code

```
strQuery = @"SELECT PASSWORD FROM IBK_USERS where upper(user_id) =upper('" + UserPrefix + "')";

try
{
    ocommand = new OracleCommand();
    if (db.GetConnection().State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        ocommand.CommandText = strQuery;
        ocommand.Connection = db.GetConnection();                       
        odatareader = ocommand.ExecuteReader();
        odatareader.Read();
```

and finally i converted above query to prevent sql injection like that

```
strQuery = @"SELECT PASSWORD FROM IBK_USERS where upper(user_id) =upper(:UserPrefix)";
try
{
    ocommand = new OracleCommand();
    if (db.GetConnection().State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        ocommand.CommandText = strQuery;
        ocommand.Connection = db.GetConnection();

        ocommand.Parameters.Add(":UserPrefix",OracleDbType.Varchar2,ParameterDirection.Input);
        ocommand.Parameters[":UserPrefix"].Value = UserPrefix;
        odatareader = ocommand.ExecuteReader();
```

but this is not working

Comment: Define "not working".  What unexpected behaviour are you seeing? What error message? What stack trace?

Comment: This is not SQL tag programming language. The code snippet is not complete.

Comment: i think cant set parameter in upper function in oracle DB

Comment: Did you open the connection? Besides, applying functions to fields in `WHERE` will result in horrible performance because you prevent the database from using any indexes. If you want to make a case-insensitive query, apply the proper collation.

Comment: yes all data are correct when i used first code it is worked..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the colon in front of the parameter name. So instead of...

```
ocommand.Parameters.Add(":UserPrefix", ...);
```

...do this...

```
ocommand.Parameters.Add("UserPrefix", ...);
```

Ditto for setting parameter value.

---

Not directly related to your question: using `upper(user_id)` in the WHERE clause may require a function-based index to run efficiently. Also, does the `user_id` really need to be a string - can't you just make it integer?